# What's the best way to store application events history or statuses

Tags: database, elasticsearch, architecture

My application have a online/offline status button. Upon clicking this button a reason to set offline/online is submitted together when setting the status. This status need to be tracked like a history.

Example:

```
Event 1: Region A goes offline due to power outage at 12 am. Set offline by operator.

Event 2: Region A goes online because power is restored at 12:15 am. Set online by technician.

Total offline time: 15 minutes
```

There might be around 10 to 20 events per day per region on a bad day but might be 0 on a perfect day.

Should I store these events into a database or something like elasticsearch is a better approach? Either way, this seems to be a common problem but I can't find a best practice to solve it. Client app need to display history of these events reliably.

It is very important to also track offline/online duration.

Comment: How will the event data be used?  E.g. displayed to users, feeding into customer SLA reports or something else?

Answer (score 0):

this is a great use of Elasticsearch, it's time based data that you can display as single points in time, or run further analysis on

check out https://aravind.dev/elastic-data-stream/ as a way to store this in Elasticsearch

Answer (score -1):

Going by your requirements and expected volumes, a serverless approach is best suited for your situation.
I'd recommend having a Lambda setup and push the records into AWS DynamoDB, with On-Demand Capacity in a JSON format.
This would significantly reduce the cost and make the entire operation simple.
The lambda can compute the outage time and append it to the json.
This will also enable you to query your data from the console or have a lambda do it periodically.

ElasticSearch is a good option if you have a lot of data coming in and you want to perform searches and analytics on the huge chunk of data, which justifies the cost of spinning up a multi-node cluster.

Answer (score -2):

> Should I store these events into a database or something like elasticsearch is a better approach?

Which database is best suited depends on the constraints that apply. ElasticSearch is not an event store but a search engine. Therefore, it is not the best fitted solution for this approach.

I would recommend to take a look at event sourcing/CQRS. Events are stored in a dedicated event store, which is a much better solution than ElasticSearch for this purpose. Your online/offline state is calculated while processing events as they happen in time and stored in a read store for query purposes. Although this approach is a bit overkill for a straight forward use case, it introduces some possibilities for future extensions to your solution. A possible framework for this is AxonIQ.

Another possibility is to take a look at Apache Kafka (which is a distributed, high volume event store). With the traffic you mention, this is probably overkill as well but is by any means more in line with your use case instead of ElasticSearch. In combination with Kafka Streams, you could calculate online/offline duration when events appear on the queue. Compared to ES/CQRS, you probably need some more development for the calculation and querying tasks because an ES framework does quite a lot of work for you which you have to roll your own while using an event store instead...

A third possibility, but probably also with the most overkill, is the (ab)use of blockchain like solutions for you use case. The latter depends on the fact if you want to introduce intelligence automatically handled while events appear in the form of smart contracts. Although this might be beneficial, I expect a bit too much overkill for this approach. Besides the known blockchain frameworks like Etherium and Hyperledger Fabric, it worth mentioning Corda as well in this collection.

Hope this clarifies some of your questions.